# Oracle PLS-00201 error in procedure across users

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have an oracle database shared by both an internal application and our website.

I know very little about oracle so will explain things how I understand it..

The database has two users APPUSER and WEBUSER when logged in (using Oracle SQL Developer) as APPUSER you can see all the tables in the database. When logged in as WEBUSER you cannot see anything but a couple of procedures, the APPUSER cannot see these procedures.

One procedure starts with:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "UPDATE_DETAIL" 
(v_ref IN APPUSER.DETAILS.REFERENCE%TYPE
,v_desc IN APPUSER.DETAILS.DESCRIPTION%TYPE
...
```

Line 2 has a red squiggly with "PLS-00201: identifier APPUSER is not declared"

I believe it has the "APPUSER.TABLE.COLUMN" because WEBUSER does not have direct access to the tables.

I have executed `GRANT ALL ON UPDATE_DETAIL TO APPUSER`logged in as WEBUSER, but that did not fix the issue, WEBUSER is the owner of the procedure, but does not have anything listed in the Grants list (I assume because owner just has the rights be default?)

The Dependencies list for the procedure is also empty, but cannot find how to manually add one to it.

Not sure what else to try to fix this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a procedure owned by `WEBUSER` (and I believe from your description that `UPDATE_DETAIL` is owned by `WEBUSER`) to reference objects owned by `APPUSER`, you would need to grant `WEBUSER` privileges on those objects.  For example, as `APPUSER`

```
GRANT SELECT ON appuser.details
   TO webuser;
```

This assumes that `WEBUSER` only needs to `SELECT` from the `APPUSER.DETAILS` table.  If your procedure needs to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` data in that table, then `WEBUSER` would need to be granted additional privileges on the `APPUSER.DETAILS` table.  You'd need to make similar grants for every table in `APPUSER` that the `WEBUSER` user needs to reference.

Comment: Hi Justin, Yes, the owner of the procedure is `WEBUSER`, the procedure performs `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` commands. I performed `GRANT ALL ON APPUSER.DETAILS TO WEBUSER` then committed but it still has the same appuser must be declared message..